# Algorithm to Check if Strings are Equal Allowing Rotations and up to K Replacements

Tags: string, algorithm, hamming-distance, edit-distance, string-search

Imagine the problem of finding if one string "STR1" is a rotated version of another string "STR2". This problem is simple and just requires searching for either string in the other string concatenated with itself. However how would you solve this problem efficiently if you are allowed to replace **up to** K characters of a string and are allowed unlimited rotations.

For example consider two strings X = "abcdefgh" and Y = "pefgwarc" where K = 3. These strings are equal as you can first rotate X three moves to the left to get "defghabc". Then we replace "d" with "p", "h" with "w" and "b" with "r" to finally get "pefgwarc". Since we only replaced three characters, these strings are considered equal by this metric.

How would you go about solving this efficiently? It seems to leverage edit distance but with rotating costing nothing and only replacements being considered but I can't seem to find any well known algorithm online that solves this.